# Determine the US state from GPS coordinates without using online service

Tags: python, algorithm, gps, reverse-geocoding

I'm analyzing tweets and need to find which state (in the USA) the user was in from their GPS coordinates.  I will not have an internet connection available so I can't use an online service such as the Google Maps API to reverse geocode.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am writing the script in python so if anyone knows of a python library that I can use that would be great.  Or if anyone can point me to a research paper or efficient algorithm I can implement to accomplish this that would also be very helpful.  I have found some data that represents the state boundaries in GPS coordinates but I can't think of an efficient way to determine which state the user's coordinates are in.

Comment: Use a point in polygon algorithm to determine if the coordinate is inside of a state (represented by a polygon with GSP coordinates as points). It doesn't seem like you would be able to improve that too much, practically speaking.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thanks for pointing me in the right direction; that's exactly what I was looking for.  You can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I generally post the short answers like that as comments as it's something of a toss up as to if the poster is in the same situation as you or the poster is actually looking for something more details. Easier to delete a inaccurate comment than edit/delete an inaccurate (as far as the questioner is concerned) answer I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a point-in-polygon algorithm to determine if the coordinate is inside of a state (represented by a polygon with GAP coordinates as points). Practically speaking, it doesn't seem like you would be able to improve much upon simply checking each state one at a time, though some optimizations can be made if it's too slow.

However, parts of Alaska are on both sides of the 180th meridian which cases problems. One solution would be to offset the coordinates a bit by adding 30 degrees modulus 180 to the longitude for each GPS coordinate (user coordinates and state coordinates). This has the effect of moving the 180th meridian about 30 degrees west and should be enough to ensure that the entire US on one side of the 180th meridian.

Comment: What about Alaska. Will there be any error when mapping a GPS coordinate in say Florida, as against Alaska.

Comment: Very little chance of confusing Alaska and Florida locations, they are well separated in latitude and longitude. A little care is needed with Alaska, which has locations either side of +/- 180 longitude.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Must have missed that while looking at my globe or the islands are tiny. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the shape of the states on a logitude/latitude map, it becomes obvious that probably 70% of the boundaries are aligned with long/lat axes.  Others follow very linear or near linear paths.  It seems like a "well crafted" [bsp tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) should be the fastest way to decide which state a location is in.

The definition of "well crafted" is hard to establish, but I'd suggest that you try to balance eliminating states (whole of a state is on side A or B of this line) with quickly isolating large population centers.  Ideally if you have to subdivide a state with a line try to do so such that the large population centers are on one side of the line.

Including population dispersal in your boundary creation should improve your average case times.  Given that quite a few states have boundaries that follow rivers, some of the longest paths in your tree will probably be very deep, but you should be saving significant time over checking each state individually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but could be useful for some. It is a solution in python. Go to this [link] (https://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/) and download a geojson file for the US states.

Then try this.

**Import the packages and load in the data from the GeoJSON**

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, MultiPolygon

data = json.load(open('GeoJson/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data["features"])
```

**Extract the required field from the GeoJSON**

```
df['Location'] = df['properties'].apply(lambda x: x['NAME'])
df['Type'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x['type'])
df['Coordinates'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x['coordinates'])
```

**Create Polygon or MultiPolygon objects depending on the States type.**

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for idx, row in df.iterrows():

    if row['Type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
        list_of_polys = []
        df_row = row['Coordinates']
        for ll in df_row:
            list_of_polys.append(Polygon(ll[0]))
        poly = MultiPolygon(list_of_polys)

    elif row['Type'] == 'Polygon':
        df_row = row['Coordinates']
        poly = Polygon(df_row[0])

    else:
        poly = None

    row['Polygon'] = poly
    df_new = df_new.append(row)
```

**Drop columns we don't need**

```
df_selection = df_new.drop(columns=['type', 'properties', 'geometry','Coordinates'] )
```

**Feed in an example lat and long and see the results** - if its not right first time, switch your lat and long ;-)

```
point = Point(-81.47, 27.494) #Example GPS location for somewhere in Florida
state = df_selection.apply(lambda row: row['Location'] if row['Polygon'].contains(point) else None, axis=1).dropna()
print(state)
```